# C# - The name 'BoyorGirl' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a text adventure in C#, it's very different from XNA coding, I am triying to display the gender of the player, but it's in a different field. I get this error:

> The name 'BoyorGirl' does not exist in the current context

(The error is at line 113, column 73).

And this is the script: (I put a // where the error appears)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ....
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Start_Game();
        }

        static public void Start_Game()
        {
            int StartMenu;
            Console.WriteLine(@"Welcome Adventurer..
            Are you ready for an adventure?
            #1 Start Game
            #2 Help
            #3 Exit");
            StartMenu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (StartMenu)
            {
                case 1:
                    Start_Adventure();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Help_Menu();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not an option..");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Start_Game();
                    break;
            }
        }

        static public void Start_Adventure()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You're a normal..\nBoy/Girl?");
            string BoyorGirl;
            BoyorGirl = Console.ReadLine();
            BoyorGirl = BoyorGirl.ToLower();
            switch (BoyorGirl)
            {
                case "boy":
                    BoyorGirl = "Boy";
                    Console.Clear();
                    input_name();
                    break;
                case "girl":
                    BoyorGirl = "Girl";
                    Console.Clear();
                    input_name();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not an option..");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Start_Adventure();
                    break;

            }

        }

        public static void input_name()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're just a normal {0}, called.. input your name please.");
            string name;
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You're just a normal {0}, called {1}..", BoyorGirl, name); //The error appears here.
        }

        static public void Help_Menu()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I also want to get rid of the statics, but I don't think that's possible. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable only exists in the scope of the `Start_Adventure()` method.

If you want to use it in that method, you need to either delcare it globally or pass it into the method.

```
public static void input_name(string BoyorGirl)
{
    //Do Work Here
}
```

OR

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
         private static string BoyOrGirl;
    ...
```

if you go with the second option, remember to remove this

```
string BoyorGirl;
```

from `Start_Adventure()`

Comment: Do I seriously need to link it everytime when I want to include it in the 'game'?

Comment: Not if you make it a global variable like in my second option

Comment: > An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property - it doesn't work :(

Comment: Uppdate answer to make the variable static

Answer (score 0):

Because `BoyorGirl` is a local variable to your `Start_Adventure` method. You need to pass that variable if you want to use it:

```
    BoyorGirl = "Girl";
    Console.Clear();
    input_name(BoyorGirl);

// ....
public static void input_name(string BoyorGirl) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to following:

```
    static public void Start_Adventure()
    {
        ...
        input_name(BoyorGirl);
        ...
    }

    public static void input_name(string BoyorGirl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're just a normal {0}, called.. input your name please.");
        string name;
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("You're just a normal {0}, called {1}..", BoyorGirl, name); //The error appears here.
    }
```

The string BoyorGirl was not known in your `input_name`-method.

So you have to pass the string to the method or use a global var.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variable `BoyorGirl` in the scope of the method `Start_Adventure()`, it will not be available outside of that scope.
Therefore, you have to either change the variable to be a member of the class `Program`, or pass it to the `input_name()` method as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

A variable declared inside a method is local to that specific method and cannot be accessed from elsewhere. As such, `input_name` has no idea what `BoyorGirl` is, because it's only found in `Start_Adventure`.

What you could do is to pass the variable to `input_name`:

```
public static void input_name(string BoyorGirl)
```

and

```
input_name(BoyorGirl);
```